# How would you separately copy each line in a char array to an array of char arrays, in c?

Tags: arrays, c, char

I am trying to put each line of a char array into separate char arrays. I am having a lot of unpredictable results and can't figure out where I'm messing up. Any help or criticism would be appreciated, thanks!

```
void TempControl::show_status_lines( const char *tmpc, int numlines )
{
    int len = strlen(tmpc);
    int line = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char tmpcstr[numlines][len];

    for ( int i = 0; i < len; i ++ ) {
        if ( tmpc[i] != '\n' ) {
            tmpcstr[line][j++] = tmpc[i];
        } else {
            line ++;
            j = 0;
        }
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < numlines; i ++ ) {
        // show tmpcstr[i]...
    }
}
```

Please note: some code for drawing graphics was omitted for simplicity. I do not think any of it would be relevant here, but will include it if requested.

Comment: *"I am having a lot of unpredictable results"*- such as ?? Note that your sizing assumes `line` will never breach `numlines-1`, and you never terminate your contrived strings. Also, your "show" loop should be based on `line`, not `numlines`. The former indicates actual content, the latter indicates your assumed capacity. there are no guarantees they're synonymous.

Comment: Did you intend the C++ tag?  In C++, I wouldn't use (C-style) arrays, I would use `std::string` and `std::vector`.

Comment: you need to null terminate your strings in `tmpcstr`. `tmpcstr[numlines][len]` is not valid c++ because neither dimension is a compile time constant

Comment: I'm glad you are able to [find an answer to your question](/revisions/73652617/3), however, on Stack Overflow questions and answers are separate fields. If you would like to provide an answer to your problem, please use the answer field below instead of editing it into your question body.